# HUGO IN function not accepting variable as ITEM

Tags: go, hugo, go-templates

I am using the `IN` function of Hugo that can be used as `in SET ITEM` as defined at [Hugo Documentation for IN](https://gohugo.io/functions/in/)

I am trying to filter out posts of a particular category by the below code

```
{{ range where .Site.Pages "Section" "products"}}
   {{ if in .Params.categories "New Arrival" }}
          <li>{{ .Title }}</li>
   {{end}}
{{end}}
```

the above code works completely fine.

**But if I use a variable instead of a string for the `ITEM`. It always returns `False`.**

```
{{ $display_product_cat := "New Arrival" }}

{{ range where .Site.Pages "Section" "products"}}
      {{ if in .Params.categories $display_product_cat }}
          <li>{{ .Title }}</li>
      {{end}}
{{end}}
```

**The above code does not work as expected.**

Wondering if I am missing something here. Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: What do you mean "ITEM always returns false"?  There's nothing called ITEM in your code, and there's nothing returning a boolean... what exactly do you see is "false"?

Comment: @flimzy thanks for your reply. But ITEM I mean the second parameter of the IN function. When I use in function in the first snippet of code I use a string as the second parameter. But in the second snippet I am using a variable as the second parameter. This does not work for some reason.

Comment: In what way does it not work? What output or error do you see?

Comment: @Flimzy, well it does not give any error the build just works fine.But for the above code it in second snippet `if in .Params.categories $display_product_cat` must be `TRUE` but it always returns 'FALSE'.

Comment: That sounds a lot like your `.Params.categories` list doesn't contain `"New Arrival"`, and that your code is actually working.

Comment: This is my real dilemma. That is the reason I have posted 2 snippets, the first one works fine where I use a string , but in the second one I assign that string to a variable and it stops working. @Flimzy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180407/discussion-between-maharshi-raval-and-flimzy).

Comment: I've tested your snippet and for me works correctly, I'm on version `Hugo Static Site Generator v0.40.2 darwin/amd64` and the code snippet that I've used `{{ $cat := "Tutorial" }}
{{ range .Site.Pages }}
   {{ if in .Params.categories $cat }}
          <li>{{ .Title }}</li>
   {{end}}
{{end}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can test what the boolean is by something like:

```
{{ $i := in .Params.categories "New Arrival" }}
{{ $i }} ## will output true|false

{{ $var := "New Arrival" }}
{{ $j := in .Params.categories $var }}
{{ $j }} ## will output true|false
```

If it's giving false outcomes, you might need to inspect how your `.Params` are actually constructed (what pattern are they in, etc.).

Providing more info will allow a better debug for you (like the snippet of your Params).